# django-admin: "super() argument 1 must be type, not None" when overriding save method

Tags: python, django, types, django-admin

Well, another unhelpful error has caused me to spend an hour trying to sort this problem.

I have a model 'CompanyProfile' that has been working until recently, but now when i try to save the model through the admin, I get an error which seems to be telling me that the Object reference is null. I have no idea how to sort this.

I'm doing everything as usual:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    super(CompanyProfile, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

I've restarted the server, reinstalled django, cleared the database, and still no luck. Anyone have any ideas or had this problem before?

Comment: I assume that `CompanyProfile` is the right name of your model class? Does it work if you remove the code snippet from above?

Comment: yep, the name is correct, and yes it does work if I remove the overriden save method which is strange. I think it may be a bug as opposed to my own incompetence!

Comment: can you maybe post the stack trace as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's a cyclic import issue?
http://markmail.org/message/zothlfayqkbidqfh#query:+page:1+mid:3cnpcw3e4cgo3cas+state:results

In the example here, he had an import statement in a signal that was the culprit.

You could check globals() for similar symptoms..

Comment: I had this error again and came back across this answer which I never accepted! Thanks

Comment: @pastylegs It's funny you're a familiar face on django Q's now  :) Looks like I was barely active on SO last year too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use args/kwargs when overriding model methods: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

> It's also important that you pass
>   through the arguments that can be
>   passed to the model method -- that's
>   what the *args, **kwargs bit does.
>   Django will, from time to time, extend
>   the capabilities of built-in model
>   methods, adding new arguments. If you
>   use *args, **kwargs in your method
>   definitions, you are guaranteed that
>   your code will automatically support
>   those arguments when they are added.

Comment: No, you don't need to - you should, but there is no way this could affect the arguments of super(), could it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following the `save()` override example from [the docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).  Note the use of `*args, **kwargs`.  If that doesn't work then something is serious messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess, but is this save method definately part of the CompanyProfile models class and is your indentation correct?